# Intellij inspection rule to simplify conditional algorithms

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sonarqube

We have some short methods that convert some values from one domain to another, it usually have a huge `switch` block or several `ifs`, for instance:

```
private DomainB translateSomething(final DomainA data) {
    DomainB result = null;
    if (data != null) {
            if (CONSTANT_A_VALUE_X.equals(data)) {
                result = CONSTANT_B_VALUE_X;
            } else if (CONSTANT_A_VALUE_Y.equals(data)) {
                result = CONSTANT_B_VALUE_Y;
            } else if (CONSTANT_A_VALUE_Z.equals(data)) {
                result = CONSTANT_B_VALUE_Z;
            } else {
                result = CONSTANT_B_VALUE_W;
            }
    }
    return result;
}
```

It may be a `switch` instead of `if`, or it can have more than one condition per result, or even receive more than one domain on the method parameters in order to help to determine one single result, that is why it could not be a map.

When I see this I apply a short-circuit on the first condition, and remove all `else` blocks and instead of assigning the value to a variable which will be returned in the end, I put the return inside the condition itself, resulting the following code:

```
private DomainB translateSomething(final DomainA data) {
    if (data == null) {
        return null;
    }
    if (CONSTANT_A_VALUE_X.equals(data)) {
        return CONSTANT_B_VALUE_X;
    }
    if (CONSTANT_A_VALUE_Y.equals(data)) {
        return CONSTANT_B_VALUE_Y;
    }
    if (CONSTANT_A_VALUE_Z.equals(data)) {
        return CONSTANT_B_VALUE_Z;
    }
    return CONSTANT_B_VALUE_W;
}
```

I'm tired to do it several times, I know IntelliJ helps a lot with inspections rules, is there some rule on IntelliJ that suggest this?

Comment: I realize that this is not quite what you asked, but an alternative approach might be to provide a custom converter for each of those types. If the conversions are similar enough (which they seem to be, since all of your returns are of type `DomainB`), you can create a code template for the converter and simply create another one from the template whenever you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use "*Move return closer to computation of the value..*" quick-fix of *'return' separated from the result computation* inspection (Java | Code style issues | 'return' separated from the result computation), then apply "*remove redundant 'else'*" quick-fixes of *Redundant 'else'* inspection (Java | Control flow issues | Redundant 'else').

[image]

Comment: I have increased the severity of those and then it started reporting as expected!